# What should i return to browser if server didn't do what user expected while processing ajax request

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax

i got simple jquery function:

```
function newCategoryAjax() {
    $.post("/ajax/addcategory", {
        name: $('#id_new_category').val()
    }).done(function (obj, sta) {
        $('select#id_category').append($('<option>', {
            value: obj.id,
            text: obj.name,
            selected: true
        })).multiselect('refresh');

    });
}
```

My server responds with new category id and name on success.
But there are instances when server wont do what user expects - ie. didn't create category because 'name' failed validation or there is already category with this name.

What is best practice, what my server should return in this case? Should response still have status=200 and error information in context dictionary like `{'error':'duplicate'}` or should it have status=500 or something like that?

Comment: You've identified the two main lines of thought on this. Both have strong adherents. Which you decide to use is really up to you.

Comment: You should return json from server gatting e.g a data status. If `data.staus === 'success'`, fill select element with `data.options` (`data.result`, whatever), otherwise provide error message.

Comment: However if you decide to use an _error_ status code then I wouldn't use 500 status code for invalid parameters because it identifies a server error. Pick proper 4xx status code (400, 403 or 409 according to specific error) and go with that.

Comment: I agree with A.Wolff, You should not change the status, just return some data that indicates the status, the http status is used for other purposes and in future it might be confusing for you

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Could you elaborate? What are pros end cons of using status vs using json object to signal error?